# How to add Content-Type: application/octet-stream to .Net Core header

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

**I want to accomplish this, is there any trick**

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-type", "application/octet-stream"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set content headers with `HttpContent` object, like below.

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    //code logic here

    //...
}
```

Besides, for more information about using `IHttpClientFactory` to create an `HttpClient` instance in ASP.NET Core, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1